# Git Not Pushing Committed Files

Tags: git

git shows that all desired directories/files have been successfully committed to my local master branch via:
`git ls-tree -r --name-only master`

This command `git push -u $destination_git_branch $source_git_branch` informs me that `Everything up-to-date`

**Problem:**
None of my files are actually being written to the destination repo.

Therefore, I double-checked that my git hook `post-receive` was executable and had the correct directory information:

```
git --work-tree=/home/username/public_html --git-dir=/home/username/public_html/git/production.git checkout -f
```

**update:**
This verifies that the correct repo is targeted by the local git push command:

```
$ git remote -v
$destination_git_branch ssh_user@123.456.789.12:public_html/git/staging.git (fetch)
$destination_git_branch ssh_user@123.456.789.12:public_html/git/staging.git (push)
```

**Note:**
the `--git-dir=` was incorrect and set for `production` rather than `staging`.  Therefore, I re-initialized the destination repo with `git init --bare`  and on the local test server I removed, then re-added the remote/destination repo.

Same problem.

The issue seems to be that `post-receive` isn't being executed. Within `post-receive` I do have `#!/bin/sh` and I added `exec  5>> /home/adminbvcs/logs/post-receive.log; BASH_XTRACEFD="5"; PS4='$LINENO: '; set -x;` in another window I have `tail -f /home/username/logs/post-receive.log`

Nothing enters the log when I push.

The `post-receive` is executable:

```
~/public_html/git/staging.git/hooks$ stat post-receive
  File: post-receive
  Size: 320         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd04h/64772d    Inode: 2228925     Links: 1
Access: (0751/-rwxr-x--x)  Uid: ( 1059/username)   Gid: ( 1036/username)
Access: 2022-09-19 10:03:39.267891777 +0800
Modify: 2022-09-19 10:02:43.366922815 +0800
Change: 2022-09-19 10:18:55.287857468 +0800
 Birth: -
```

Sure this is a rookie error, but why aren't my files actually being push the correct location?

Comment: Do you see the commits in your remote repo?  Is your hook being executed?  If it's a shell script then you need a #!/bin/sh so either that's an issue or you provide partial info.

Comment: Re: `git push -u $destination_git_branch $source_git_branch` - `git push` needs *the name of a remote* (usually `origin`) as its first argument, not the name of a branch; `$source_git_branch` had better be `master` if your commit is only at the tip of your local `master`.

Comment: Re the hook *on* the server: `git checkout -f` means "check out the current branch" (on the server); is that also `master`? And: if it's a script, make sure it starts with `#! /bin/sh` or `#! /usr/local/bin/bash` or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: @torek just added info, see above..

Comment: OK - note that `/bin/sh` may not understand Bashisms, so that $BASH_TRACEFD and $PS4 might have no effect. You could `echo running >&5` or `>> <trace path>`. (/bin/sh may be POSIX shell, or dash, or similar; this depends on your server OS and setup.)

Comment: @torek being thorough, I tried both... I am leaving it on `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @torek tried using this `echo  running>&5 /home/adminbvcs/logs/post-receive.log; set -x;`  not putput

Comment: This almost certainly has nothing to do with the problem, but the post-receive script shouldn't bother with `--git-dir=` in it. Your intent is to check out the most recent `HEAD` commit *from* the *current* repository, after all, so why override the current repository with an explicit repository path?

Comment: In the meantime, you still haven't answered which branch is the current branch in the destination repository, or the question about the `git push` formulation, which specifies the remote improperly and uses a variable (`$source_git_branch`) that might not be set to `master`. You should still be getting log entries if the post-receive script is running, though.

Comment: @torek  Appreciate the help... the branches weren't the problem.   I figured it out. there was an incorrect setting in my .gitignore file.  I -re-created the file from a different server that was working and the problem vanished.  I still can't log output from `post-receive` but that is non-essential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MIND BOGGLING SOLUTION:**

Being a git rookie, I suspected that maybe I had done something wrong within my `.gitignore` file.  Therefore, I `mv .gitignore .gitignore.bak`  and created a fresh `.gitignore`

BAM!!! everything worked.

At this point I ran a `diff .gitignore .gitignore.bak` command to see what the bad setting was....  There wasn't a bad setting:

```
$ diff .gitignore .gitignore.bak
26,27c26,27
< /push-staging.sh
< /pull-staging.sh
---
> /push.sh
> /pull.sh
30c30
< /.gitignore.bak
---
> /test-push-db-import.sh
34c34
< /test-push-db-import.sh
---
> 
40a41
> #/wp-content/themes/generatepress*/
```

The **PROBLEM** seems to be that the `.gitignore` somehow had incorrect permissions:

```
$ stat .gitignore.bak 
  File: .gitignore.bak
  Size: 1210        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 810573      Links: 1
Access: (0640/-rw-r-----)  Uid: ( 1037/username)   Gid: ( 1036/username)
Access: 2022-09-19 11:10:00.960804347 +0800
Modify: 2022-09-19 10:32:54.604206792 +0800
Change: 2022-09-19 10:33:16.186992558 +0800
 Birth: -
$ stat .gitignore
  File: .gitignore
  Size: 1205        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 800408      Links: 1
Access: (0660/-rw-rw----)  Uid: ( 1037/username)   Gid: ( 1036/username)
Access: 2022-09-19 11:10:00.960804347 +0800
Modify: 2022-09-19 10:57:27.408224628 +0800
Change: 2022-09-19 10:57:27.408224628 +0800
 Birth: -
```